# Why Visual Studio (2019) breaks on LogCritical

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 breaks in logger.LogCritical call.

And I don't understand why.

I have all exception settings cleared

[image]

but there is catch block, and inside it VS2019 breaks and highlights it green

[image]

logger implementation is Microsoft default logger

[image]

Do I miss anything and is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Upd:

Definitely related to LogCritical, because after I changed it to LogError, it doesn't break anymore.

Also, another thing I noticed, the following code doesn't break on LogCritical

[image]

And the code which breaks is executed in thread pool(not sure if it matters).

Comment: Maybe access rights? Try running a admin.